# Invalid form not returning JSON/form field errors in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to use modal forms with AJAX in Django and I've got it so that the modal shows the form content, and it submits/works correctly when there are no form errors, however when there are form errors it doesnt seem to send the response back in AJAX (at least this is my guess). When there are form errors it will refresh the page and show the form in a new page (not in a modal) and the form will have the user input saved and it will show the form field errors. If this sounds confusing let me know and I can upload some screenshots of what its doing.

Here is my jQuery/AJAX...

```
<script>
function apply_form_field_error(fieldname, error) {
    var input = $("#id_" + fieldname),
        container = $("#div_id_" + fieldname),
        error_msg = $("<span />").addClass("help-inline ajax-error").text(error[0]);

    container.addClass("error");
    error_msg.insertAfter(input);
}

function clear_form_field_errors(form) {
    $(".ajax-error", $(form)).remove();
    $(".error", $(form)).removeClass("error");
}

function django_message(msg, level) {
    var levels = {
        warning: 'alert',
        error: 'error',
        success: 'success',
        info: 'info'
    },
    source = $('#message_template').html(),
    template = Handlebars.compile(source),
    context = {
        'tags': levels[level],
        'message': msg
    },
    html = template(context);

    $("#message_area").append(html);
}

function django_block_message(msg, level) {
    var source = $("#message_block_template").html(),
        template = Handlebars.compile(source),
        context = {level: level, body: msg},
        html = template(context);

    $("#message_area").append(html);
}

var formAjaxSubmit = function(form, modal) {
   $(form).on("submit", "#create_form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        url = self.attr("action"),
        ajax_req = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: self.find("#id_name").val()
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              $(modal).modal('toggle');
              alert("Design created!");  // <-- This is just a placeholder for now for testing
              window.location.replace("{% url 'engineering:gaas_wafer_design_list' %}");
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
                    if (index === "__all__") {
                        django_message(value[0], "error");
                    } else {
                        apply_form_field_error(index, value);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
$('#create-button').click(function() {
   $('#form-modal-body').load('create/', function () {
       formAjaxSubmit('#form-modal-body form', '#form-modal');
   });
});
```

Here is my gaas_wafer_design_form_inner.html (the form that gets loaded into the modal content)...

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form id="create_form" method="post" action="{% url 'engineering:gaas_wafer_design_create' %}">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.design_ui.id_for_label }}"><b>Design UI</b></label>
        {% render_field form.design_ui class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.design_ui.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.emitting.id_for_label }}"><b>Emitting</b></label>
        {% render_field form.emitting class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.emitting.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.contact_location.id_for_label }}"><b>Contact Location</b></label>
        {% render_field form.contact_location class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.contact_location.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.optical_power.id_for_label }}">Optical Power</label>
        {% render_field form.optical_power class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.optical_power.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.design_date.id_for_label }}"><b>Design Date</b></label>
        {% render_field form.design_date class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.design_date.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.designer.id_for_label }}"><b>Designer</b></label>
        {% render_field form.designer class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.designer.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.designer_ui.id_for_label }}">Designer UI</label>
        {% render_field form.designer_ui class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.designer_ui.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.design_document.id_for_label }}">Design Document</label>
        {% render_field form.design_document class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.design_document.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group" style="float:left;">
        <label for="{{ form.in_trash.id_for_label }}">In Trash</label>
        {% render_field form.in_trash class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.in_trash.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.inactive_date.id_for_label }}">Inactive Date</label>
        {% render_field form.inactive_date class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.inactive_date.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.notes.id_for_label }}">Notes</label>
        {% render_field form.notes class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.notes.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <!--/.row-->
  <span style="float:right;">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

and here is my Django view...

```
class GaasWaferDesignCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, 

AjaxTemplateMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'engineering/gaas_wafer_designs/gaas_wafer_design_form_inner.html'
    ajax_template_name = 'engineering/gaas_wafer_designs/gaas_wafer_design_form_inner.html'
    form_class = GaasWaferDesignForm
    form = GaasWaferDesignForm()
    model = GaasWaferDesign
    success_url = reverse_lazy('engineering:gaas_wafer_design_list')
    success_message = "yes!"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the request is ajax, save the form and return a json response.
        Otherwise return super as expected.
        """
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.created_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps("success"),
                content_type="application/json")

        else:
            object = form.save(commit=False)
            object.created_by = self.request.user
            object.save()

        return super(GaasWaferDesignCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """
        We haz errors in the form. If ajax, return them as json.
        Otherwise, proceed as normal.
        """
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps(form.errors),
                content_type="application/json")
        return super(GaasWaferDesignCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Any help you can give is much appreciated!

Comment: So if you add `console.log(data);` under `error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {` what do you see? Or does that never get called?

Comment: Correct, it doesnt get called since the invalid form refreshes the page. I think whats going on is upon submission (success or error) it goes directly to the Django view for handling. In the success function this is ok because it creates the object in the database and refreshes the page to the list of objects which is what I wanted in the first place. But on invalid form submission it sends the pafe to the GaasWaferDesignCreateView for handling, which renders a new page with the errors instead of sending the JSON data back to the modal without closing it or refreshing the page